# Publish a react native app in the google play store that is using google authentication

Tags: android, react-native, google-oauth, google-play-console, firebase-test-lab

I've created an app using react native, which I am currrently publishing in the google play store. The app has a login screen where the user needs to press a google sign-in button and bacause of this is was rejected, as the google play team was not able to login.

My reaction was to write a robo script using firebase test lab, but elements in react native are not found by the script (TouchableOpacity).

If creating a robo sciprt for react native is not possible, then how should I enable the google play team to access the app? Is there some other solution?

Comment: There's a place to give them a username and password in the play store.  Create an account for them and give them the info.

Comment: That was not the case for me. They are still rejecting the app with the reason being not being able to authenticate. They are sending me a screenshot of my login screen, not being able to press 'Sign In With Google'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem came from the fact that google play signs my application with seperate fingerprint, for whick I did not account for.